# Color not changing after the change of geoJSON property

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, mapbox

I am using mapbox and leaflet to plot lines in a map and below is my code:

```
var lines= {


        "type":"FeatureCollection",

        "features": [

      {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry":{"type":"LineString", 
       "coordinates":[[103.85909,1.2941],[103.85895,1.2940450000000001],[103.85881,1.29399]]},
       "properties": {"id":"01","score":10}
      }


// totally having 100 elements in the array

                   ]};

var map = L.map('map').setView([1.3096622448984000, 103.7689017333800], 12);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=token', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();

    var options = {
            position: 'topleft',
            title: 'Search',
            placeholder: 'enter link id ',
            maxResultLength: 15,
            threshold: 0.5,
            showInvisibleFeatures: true,
            showResultFct: function(feature, container) {
                props = feature.properties;
                var name = L.DomUtil.create('b', null, container);
                name.innerHTML = props.id;

                container.appendChild(L.DomUtil.create('br', null, container));

                var cat = props.id
                    info = '' + cat + ', ' + 'th link';
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(info));
            }
        };

    var searchCtrl = L.control.fuseSearch(options);

    searchCtrl.addTo(map);


    var geojson;

    function getColor(d) {


           if(d=10){
               return '#ff0000';
           }

           else if(d<10){
               return '#00FF00';
           }
           else{
               return '#00FF00';

           }
    } 


    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: getColor(feature.properties.score),


            fillOpacity: 0.7,

        };
    }


    function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color:'#0000FF',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });


    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }

    info.update(layer.feature.properties);

    }
function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    info.update();
}
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
}
var info = L.control();


info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4><b>August 2016: <b></h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>Link ' + props.id + '</b><br />'  
        : 'Hover over a link');


};


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
     feature.layer = layer;

    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,


    });
    var popupContent = 
      '<b>Link ' + feature.properties.id + '</b>';

    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);          
    feature.layer = layer;

}




function mapupdatecolor(){




          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",

            url: 'http://'+backend+':8081/lines', 
            success: function(data) {


//data is 100 elements data array in the form of           [{"street":1,"score":8},....


                for (i = 0; i <100; i++) { 

                    console.log("1 time score in console--"+zones['features'][i]['properties']['score']);
                    lines['features'][i]['properties']['score']=data[i].score;
                    console.log(data[i].score)
                    console.log("2 time score in console after change--"+lines['features'][i]['properties']['score']);

                }

                if (geojson) {

                    geojson.remove(); 
                    console.log("removed");

                }




                geojson = L.geoJson(lines, {
                     style: style,
                     onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                }).addTo(map);
                console.log("update done")
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                alert(thrownError);
              },
            complete: function() {

              setTimeout(mapupdatecolor, 1000);
            }
          });










}

geojson = L.geoJson(lines, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);


info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};




searchCtrl.indexFeatures(lines.features, ['id']);
info.addTo(map);

setTimeout( mapupdatecolor, 1000);
```

So  `setTimeout( mapupdatecolor, 1000)` lines calls the ajax call for every time period and then the score of the line is expected to be changed.For the first element initially score is 10 and after the first call it should change to 8 and the color also should change.When I run this it displays

```
    1 time score in console--10
    8
    2 time score in console after change--8
```

in the console.But the color of line is  not changing(it should change because in the getColor function d is 8 and not 10 so it should change to green instead of red ).Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem :

```
if(d=10){
    return '#ff0000';
}
```

The expression `(d=10)` is always true. Use `(d === 10)` instead.

IMHO you could have tested the behaviour of your `getColor` function before asking and showing such a big amount of code. The question seems to be related with Leaflet and in fact it is not.